# Not able to plot the graph from "./mplot run"

Tags: python, memory-profiling

I've done "mprof run --python " and post that when I am trying to plot the graph("mprof plot"). But I don't see any graph being plotted.

```
vikas@host:/home/vikas/memory_profiler-0.32$ ./mprof run --python ../asl
```

mprof: Sampling memory every 0.1s

running as a Python program...

```
vikas@host:/home/vikas/memory_profiler-0.32$ cat mprofile_20150224005550.dat
```

CMDLINE python ../asl

MEM 1.316406 1424768150.5671

MEM 6.539062 1424768150.6675

MEM 8.812500 1424768150.7678

MEM 8.812500 1424768150.8681

MEM 8.812500 1424768150.9684

Answer (score 0):

you can plot the result with the command

```
./mprof plot
```

This will plot the latest *.dat file (which is the output of mprof run) that it will find. You can also give it a *.dat file if you have several, for example:

```
./prof plot plot myscript_20141108113511.dat
```